# Impossible probability question?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint density
$$f(x,y) = x+ y, \ 0 \leq x \leq 1, \ 0 \leq y \leq 1.$$
Let $T = \max(X,Y).$ I want to find $\mathbb{E}[XT].$ I claim this question is impossible.

First of all, the joint density of $X$ and $T$ does not exist. Since
$$P(X = T) = P(X >Y) > 0,$$
and the Lebesgue measure of the set $ \{ (x,y) \  | \  x = y\}$ is $0$, I don't see how any density could exist. Conditioning leads to nothing, since in order to condition on you need the density. It seems like any method I tried has failed.

This was on a previous qualifying exam, so obviously there is a solution. What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't done much probability,  but where does that $f(x,y)$ function come up in the problem other than being defined?

Comment: What makes you think that $E[XT]$ can only be computed if $X,T$ have a joint density?

Comment: $X$ and $T$ are bounded and their joint distribution (rather than density) can be found, so $E[XT]$ exists and is clearly in $[0,1]$.  Try conditioning on $X>Y$ and $X \le Y$ which by symmetry each have probability $\frac12$

Comment: Hint: $E[XT]=\int x \max \{x,y\} f(x,y)dxdy$

Comment: @geetha290krm I guess because I’m stupid and didn’t try the easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a density, therefore you can simply integrate (hopeful I didn't make any mistakes but don't trust it) :
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 x \max(x,y) f(x,y) dydx &= \int_0^1\int_0^x x^2(x+y) dydx+\int_0^1\int_x^1 xy(x+y) dydx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^x x^2(x+y) dydx+\int_0^1\int_x^1 xy(x+y) dydx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^4}{2} dx + \int_0^1\left( \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{2} +\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^4}{3}\right) dx\\
&=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{15}\\
&=\frac{4}{15}
\end{align*}